# EXTJS IFRAME and security

Tags: html, security, extjs, extjs4.2

I am still new to web development, is it safe to use an IFRAME to download a file, my site is HTTPS and the iframe SRC url is also HTTPS, both are in the same domain.  I am reading a lot about security risks but still joining the dots together.

This is the code I am using.

```
var iFrame = Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            cls: 'x-hidden',
            id: 'iFrameId',
                autoEl: {
                    tag: 'iframe',
                    src: https_url
                }, 
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function () {
                    Ext.defer(function(){
                        // destory iframe after 3 minutes
                        iFrame.destroy()
                        },180000);
                    }
            }
        });
```

Comment: How do you mean by "safe"? What threats do you wish to defend your download against?

Comment: I am trying to understand security risks, exploits, best practices,from the research I have done so far (and my position may change on further education), as long as I am connecting to the same domain then I should be safe.

Comment: You shouldn't have any security issues trying to download a file, this is not how apps get hacked.